# How do you run devtools on IntelliJ?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea, devtools

I am trying to use spring boot's devtools on IntelliJ (2019.3 Ultimate Edition). I have added the dependency in the pom.xml file as follows:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

and I have enabled compiler.automake.allow.when.app.running and ide.windowSystem.autoShowProcessPopup under Registry.

I am getting the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class
>   jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader cannot be cast to
>   class java.net.URLClassLoader

From what I can find online, this seems to be a problem with lower spring boot devtools versions being incompatible with java versions 9 and above, but I'm using spring boot version 2.2.2 which should work with my java version 13. Please advise!